# Keyboard shortcuts in Xcode stop working

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I first noticed this with `Cmd-/` occasionally refusing to work for comment-uncomment lines of code. But now (having just gone to XCode 4.1, although that may not be related) it's happened with `Cmd-B` to build as well.

I can't figure out what I'm doing to cause this, or if there's any pattern to when it happens.

Comment: Noticed that this can be fixed by Cmd-T to open a new tab with the same file. Old tab broken, new tab works.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to use command-option-R to perform a "Find and Replace". Xcode just ignores the key sequence. I can change it to anything else and it works, just not command-option-R. Wonder if there is not some kind of keyboard processing issue. Same in Xcode 8 as Xcode 10 beta

Answer (score 2):

Hit `command+[` once and then `command+/` starts working. You can hit `command+]` again to undo the indentation effect.

Originally posted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27773923/2082569)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been fixed in 4.2. As an answer, perhaps unsatisfying, but at least it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my keyboard was working in other files the current opened file was locked.
Just reveal in finder your current file where your keyboard was not working, and go to info (Cmd+I) of this file in finder and unlock this file. Your keyboard will start working for this file.

My page was locked using cmd+/.