# Xcode 8 Beta 4 - Comment Shortcut Disabled

Tags: xcode8, xcode8-beta4

I just updated to Xcode 8 Beta 4 and the shortcut `cmd` + `/` to comment a line is not working..

In the dropdown menu it's disabled:

[image]

There's a way to activate it again?

Comment: I've just upgraded from Beta 3 to Beta 5 and experienced this issue for the first time. Quitting and reopening XCode fixes it for me, at least temporarily.

Comment: Xcode 8 Beta 6 - same issue here...

Comment: How did u get the dark theme for xcode?

Comment: @KumarC  > System Preferences > General > Use dark menu bar and dock :)

Comment: Fixed (for me) in Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62) - released ~Nov 1, 2016.

Comment: Fixed in v 8.1 after update, tool installation, and restart of Xcode.

Comment: It can be related to a macOS update, not to Xcode. Fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41614038/661121

Answer (score 166, accepted):

I fixed it following the steps here: https://twitter.com/kolpanic/status/763323546814844928

In Terminal: `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl`

Reboot your system.

Comment: I think we have a winner! this solved my problem. I have tested all other workarounds, none worked. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I believe it activates the new Xcode 8 Source Editor Extensions https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/414/

Comment: @DanielStorm the system

Comment: This is astounding. It was broken in the betas but I expected it to resolve itself by the time the public release went out. In a public release of an IDE we have to punch a cryptic command into shell and reboot to get _code comments_ to work! Comeon! /minirant

Comment: Above solution not worked for me xCode Version 8.1 beta (8T29o). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Same here. It does not work for Version 8.1 beta (8T29o)

Comment: If you have release and beta Xcode -> I renamed Xcode beta app to "Xcode81.app", quit the Xcodes, then run the command in terminal and it worked finally, unless you start the beta, then need to rename again and repeat.

Comment: @Arthur I just needed to rename the beta after running the command then restarting xcode. Didn't need to run the command and/or reboot again.

Comment: With Xcode 8.1 , it works after reboot. But the after macbook's sleep it isn't working and wants again terminal and reboot. Any solution?

Comment: See my answer if this still doesn't work for you on OS X 10.11.

Comment: Just started with xcode, the first thing I was looking for is to comment a line, and it's not even working. Unbelievable.

Comment: I'm sure some guy at Apple is doing this on purpose. Just laughing at all the work arounds. Cheap thrills indeed. Block comments is just such a fundamental for any IDE...

Comment: Thanks this problem was occurring in Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) also. and above solution worked like charm

Comment: I partially agree with Saleh, but unfortunately it came back the next day. This is getting very frustrating.

Comment: Worked for me without a reboot. OSX 10.12/8.1

Comment: You know the worst part, there's a shortcut in the touch bar of the new MBP to access this command, but they couldn't fix the bug, still not working and need to do this sometimes.

Answer (score 99):

If `Cmd-/` still doesn't work in Xcode 8 on an OS X 10.11 (and apparently on a macOS Sierra - thanks to @DanBlakemore), and `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl` and a reboot didn't help, **try the following**.

1. Close Xcode.
2. Open `/Applications` in Finder, and rename `Xcode.app` to `Xcode2.app` (or any other name).
3. Rename it back to `Xcode.app`, and relaunch.

**It should work now**.

The problem seems to be that for whatever reason the system "uninstalls" Xcode extensions at some point, and won't "install" them again. This can be checked by opening Console, and grepping for `INSTALL`. If you have `INSTALLED`/`UNINSTALLED` for `com.apple.dt.XcodeBuiltInExtensions`, it won't work if `UNINSTALLED` was the last action on it, and will work it if was `INSTALLED`.

Figured this out when debugging an Xcode 8 extension.

Comment: Still broken for me, unfortunately.

Comment: This works for when this happens on Sierra (10.12.1) and Xcode 8.2.  It also works without a restart, which is nice as I have achieved perfect window placement and must preserve it.  Does anyone have a radar for this yet?

Comment: @DanBlakemore thanks for the info, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Crazy that this works, thank you so much for figuring this out

Comment: What should i type in console to check is it installed or not?

Comment: This is better than the currently 'accepted' solution because this doesn't require a terminal command or a reboot. Worked like a charm for me. Thank you

Comment: This issue was still found in Xcode 8.3.2, I fixed it *sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl* and rename Xcode.app steps **without reboot** just now.

Comment: It worked for me after I tried to install clang-format for Xcode8 (I use El Capitan 10.11.6 and Xcode 8.2). Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The script mentioned above didn't work right away for me. I had Xcode 8 and 8.1 GM installed and was working with both of them off and on. I ran the script in the terminal, restarted my computer, opened Xcode and it still didn't work. So then I created a new directory in `Applications` and moved the GM into that directory. That seemed to fix it.

TL;DR
If you have multiple versions of Xcode installed:

- Run in terminal: `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl`
- Restart your computer
- Create a new directory in `Applications`
- Move the other version into that directory
- Restart Xcode and enjoy!

Comment: #thanksapple. Making our Swift 3 conversion that much more fun... This was driving me nuts for a few days

Answer (score 5):

As explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587855/7698127), here's a solution that **doesn't require a reboot**:

1. Close Xcode
2. In the Application folder, rename Xcode.app (or similar) to Xcode2.app. You might need to type in your password.
3. Open Xcode, then close it.
4. Rename Xcode2.app back to what it was before.
5. *(Optional) Spend 5 minutes wondering why this worked.*

Answer (score 4):

Just update to Xcode8 release, then open Xcode8 and restart Mac.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html

> To use the Editor's Comment/Uncomment Selection and Add Documentation commands—as well as other installed Xcode Extensions—on OS X version 10.11, launch Xcode and install additional system components, then restart your Mac. (26106213)

Answer (score 3):

Go to App Store, check for system update(iTunes, MacOSX). Update all of them.

It should be fixed once its done.

Comment: Just updated the OS.. in the Editor menu now I can see `Comment Selection` active.. but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I rebooted, now it is working.

Then when I started beta 4 it asked me to "install required components" a second time.   Don't know if related or not.

Comment: This worked for me with the released version of Xcode 8.

Answer (score 2):

I applied @junjie 's method

> sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl

It works well on Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002) only except for specific files.

Then, I found the reason.

> /* Comment ...
>   //*/

This type of comment has made it inoperable.

After the line containing above comment type, "Comment Selection" didn't work.

Erase or change them.

Answer (score 0):

xcode->preferences->key buildings-> filter, search comment

see if there are conflicts for key of "command + / ", if yes, delete others unless "Comment Selection"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jndPV.png)

Answer (score 0):

This made it for me:

Goto System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts

Add a new shortcut like this:

[image]

Voila! It works for me!

As you can see the shortcut you choose will also end up besides this command in Editor menu in Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Not work now work....!! I cannot figure it out anymore. xcode developers gave me big agony. :(

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any of less or more complicated steps,

Try to quit and relaunch Xcode.

In my case, it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

`xcode->preferences->key buildings`, or,

`"command + ,",` then search `"comment selection"`
change the key `"command + /"`