# I can no longer comment code using Xcode 8.0

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Since I updated Xcode to version 8.0 (8A218a) the commenting command (command + /) doesn't work anymore. I'm wondering whether someone is facing the same issue.

Comment: It's a bug, and it's fixed in version 8.1

Comment: Yes, it is fixed now. This makes you wonder, how can they release a buggy version of Xcode where this is broken! Wouldn't they test this most basic functionality first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Terminal: `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl`

Reboot your system.

dublicated in [Xcode 8 Beta 4 - Comment Shortcut Disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712365/xcode-8-beta-4-comment-shortcut-disabled)

Comment: "sudo: /usr/libexec/xpccachectl: command not found" does anyone know why?