# Xcode 8 Comment shortcut (cmd + /) not working

Tags: xcode, xcode8

The Solution here :

[Xcode 8 Beta 4 - Comment Shortcut Disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712365/xcode-8-beta-4-comment-shortcut-disabled)

Does not work for me . Some files are accepting the shortcut , but some aren't .

This problem has persisted for a while (Since Xcode 8 beta) .

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the xcode that causes the shortcut to fail .

Comment Shortcut Works :

[image]

Comment Shortcut Does not work (for all lines of code below that line ) 
[image]

Comment: only happens if the double slash is on the last line of the comment block . Bug report filed .