# Can't comment selection

Tags: xcode, comments

Sometimes, it seems I can't comment my code with the usual shortcut (`command` + `/`) under Xcode 8 Beta 4. The option is disabled in the menu (screenshot below).

Do you have any idea why?
Am I the only one having this issue?

[image: Screenshot of the disabled command]

EDIT: It seems to work again after restarting Xcode... Still looking from where it comes. It's a bit annoying...

EDIT2: It still occurs on Xcode 8.1. Maybe because I have 2 versions of Xcode installed (normal and beta)? Can't fix it anymore with a simple restart!

EDIT3: the proposed `xpccachectl` command to fix it doesn't exist on MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: Still happens even in  Xcode 8.1 installed from Mac App Store.

Comment: And also 8.2.1.......

Comment: Solution of this problem can be found in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712365/xcode-8-beta-4-comment-shortcut-disabled

Comment: Same in xcode 8.2.1, @Apple: i recommend naming your super IDE to xxcode to be more descriptive with all these !@#!@ bugs inside

Comment: Seeing this in Xcode 8.2.1 as well :-)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631840/xcode-command-slash-shortcut-to-comment-only-works-sometimes

Comment: Hard restart for me fixed the problem..not sure if this will help anyone as of today

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Exit Xcode
2. Type `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl` in Terminal
3. Restart Xcode
4. Restart your Mac if needed

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39135831/2854405)

Comment: Reboot the systems works for me. Only restart Xcode not.

Comment: Unfortunately on macOS High Sierra there is no `xpccachectl` at this location -> `sudo: /usr/libexec/xpccachectl: command not found`.

Comment: @AleksanderGrzyb So how did you solve this issue? I am facing the same issue on macOS High Sierra

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava unfortunately not.

Answer (score 90):

Try this.  Out of all the other suggestions, this was the only one that worked for me.

Go to your applications folder and rename Xcode to whatever you want, then open the Xcode.  Check to see if the comment selection now works, if so, you can go back and rename Xcode to its default name.  If not, rename Xcode back to its original name anyway, and continue searching for another solution.

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: `/usr/libexec/xpccachectl` and reboot didn't work. Renaming Xcode.app to Ycode.app and launching it worked for me too. After it worked, I renamed app back to Xcode and it still worked. An interesting note, iTunes just updated yesterday to V12.5.3 and the comment selection stopped working. Running `macOS 10.12.1` `Xcode 8.1 (8B62)`

Comment: This issue occurs on my Mac from time to time and every time I have to try out a different method to solve it... This time yours worked well but last time I used this one  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39936649/1203713

Comment: This happens to me on a weekly basis, renaming works but is so unnecessary. Come on Apple surely your devs are annoyed by this too? Sort it out!

Comment: Woah, iTunes just updated for me, and it stopped working (2017..!)

Comment: @joe_04_04 jupp :) (Xcode 8.2.1... well, I do have an old version...)

Answer (score 23):

None of the workarounds worked for me after installing xcode 8.1 beta.  I finally found that moving the Xcode beta out of the applications folder into a different location (desktop is where i put mine) then running `sudo usr/libexec/xpccachectl` fixed the issues i was having.

Comment: I created a folder inside Applications, move xcode 8.1 beta in it, run `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl` and it works! (no restart)

Comment: Works for me too. `macOS Sierra 10.12.1` `Xcode 8.1 (8B62)`

Comment: That worked for me, but only after updating xcode location: "$ xcode-select --switch <new XCode path>".

Comment: Note: you have written `sudo usr/...` (relative path) when you meant to write `sudo /usr/...` (absolute path).

Answer (score 19):

This is a known bug in Xcode 8 beta-4 (according to Apple, on "some systems", without specifying which ones).

The good news is, according to Apple they've fixed this in beta-5. From the release notes:

> **Resolved in Xcode 8 beta 5 – IDE**
>
> The Editor’s Comment/Uncomment Selection command is functional when enabled. (27524523)

The bad news is, it's still not working for me in beta-5, even after rebooting. And for the life of me, I can't figure out what they mean by "when enabled". Since when do you have to "enable" comment/uncomment, and how would you go about doing that?

I'm on a Mac Pro cylinder running El Capitan 10.11.6, editing Swift 2.3 code.

Comment: This is still not working for me in Beta 5 as well. I restarted my computer and restarted Xcode several times. Additionally, when played around with "Command+[" and "Command + ]", they stopped working as well.

Comment: Still not working in beta 6 (on 3 different machines). I submitted a bug report, Apple marked it as a duplicate, so hopefully they are working on it. I'm just hoping they didn't mark it as a duplicate of the previous bug that they thought (and said) they fixed in beta 5, but didn't. Open Radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4976322216460288

Comment: Update: The bug # they gave me for the duplicate is NOT the same # as listed above (the bug "fixed" in beta 5). So hopefully this means they know it was not in fact fixed for everyone and opened a new bug.

Comment: For me with beta 6: on a Macbook Pro it works OK, on a Mac Mini it doesn't work.

Comment: Still not fixed, but some dude on Twitter found a workaround that works for me. `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl` then reboot. https://twitter.com/kolpanic/status/763323546814844928

Comment: The problem still occurs on official XCode 8 release. The twitter fix worked for me too... but a few days later it reverted to the same problem. So it's apparently only a temporary fix that needs to be reapplied. Very annoying as it affects such a key productivity issue as commenting blocks of code, rather than just a line at a time.

Comment: Had the same issue, restart Mac mixed it.

Comment: Have the issue and restarting didn't fix it for XCode 8 and 10.11.6

Comment: Same issue on El Capitan, Xcode 8 release version. `xpccachectl` fixed it (for now). This is absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: It seems that the `xpccachectl` spell does not work if XCode 8.1 beta is also installed. What a mess.

Comment: @spassas I renamed Xcode beta app to "Xcode81.app", quit the Xcodes, then run the command in terminal and it worked finally, unless you start the beta, then need to rename again and repeat.

Comment: This just happened to me on XCode Version 8.1 (8B62).  Apparently still not resolved!  Moving XCode into another folder, running `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl` as others have suggested, and then moving it back got it back to working.

Comment: I followed 5-8 methods to re-solve this problem in my x-code 8.x(EI- Captain OS)  but still facing the same problem. is it really enabled by Apple?

Comment: Same here. Tried moving and renaming it but still nothing. WTF. It's an industry standard for f*cks sake !

Comment: Still happening on Version 8.2 (8C38). Restarting Xcode didn't help either. It comes and goes. :(

Comment: This is among the most annoying bugs that a developer tool can have. I am ok with not having good suggestions because of broken index but I hate commenting each line in a file one by one while debugging.
NOTE: I have tried all solutions available everywhere. This bug is not resolved in Version 8.2.1 (8C1002). I follow some steps on the threads and the comment shortcut starts working but after few mins it again stops working. I hate restarting my work environment again and again x-(

Answer (score 13):

On a German Macintosh Computer, there is a System keyboard shortcut overriding the Xcode comment section shortcut.

Simply deactivate the `Hilfemenü anzeigen` shortcut. (show help)

[image: Conflicting Shortcut]

Comment: Xcode usually overrides this command, but I got exactly this behaviour once this bug shoed up. Renaming Xcode worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! Have been working (about 4 months now) without being able to comment out selection!! You made my day better :)

Comment: Couldn't manage to fix with the other solutions, this one works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

It still happens in Xcode 8.1 which was installed from Mac App Store.

I tried `sudo usr/libexec/xpccachectl`, but no luck.

I could solve this be reassigning shortcut keys again.

1. Go to Preference -> Key Bindings
2. Set some random shortcut key on `Structure -> Comment Selection` menu.
   You don't have to change all of them. One is enough.
3. Set it back to `Command + /` again.

Now it works.

[image]

Comment: How can I set it back to `Command + /` please? On my keyboard I need to use `Shift` key to do it so it set the shortcut to `Shift + Command + /`... Not working better with the `Caps Lock` activated, already tried.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately. Still no comment hotkeys :|

Answer (score 3):

My situation is a bit different(stupid?): 
I found I can't comment any line from a particular part of a particular file. I tried all the methods above with Xcode 8.1 and Xcode 8.2, but got no luck. Finally I found it was caused by a comment trick like below,

```
1 /*
2 code 
3 //*/
4 code
```

In Xcode, you can't comment line 2 with Cmd+/ because it has been commented already by /**/, which is fine. However, you can't even comment line 4 with Cmd+/, as Xcode may think it's still in a /* */ block, but it's actually not. If I remove // from line 3, then commenting line 4 works fine.

Comment: Bingo! The /* form of the "comment" doesn't even have to be a real comment. In my case it is part of a NSPredicate format. /* shows up as part of the string data, but the existence of this breaks the comments.

Comment: This was the cause of my problem too. I replaced the comments with //, rebooted my computer and the shortcut was back!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that if you have nested /* anywhere in your code it breaks the commenting from then on. [Others have reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154607/5135551) that it happens with nested block comments. However if you have nested /* anywhere, including a string it will fail.

Note the following bit of code is working with path characters `/` and wildcards `*` that together make `/*`. Anything after this line and commenting out doesn't work in XCode.

```
int foo = "this line can be commented out";

predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(cachedAudioDataURL like '*/Library/Private*/*')) AND (NOT (cachedAudioDataURL like '*/Documents/*'))"];

int bar = "broken - can't be commented out";
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a little bit of CompSci 101:

> Restart your computer

Answer (score 1):

I did as Joe_04_04. Renamed de Xcode APP to anything else and back to original name

Answer (score 1):

Fix Xcode 8 Comment/UnComment menus: "`sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl`" then reboot.

This works for me. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

This bug also happens on Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002) of macOS 10.12.3 (16D32). And there is another Xcode 7.3, which is fine, also installed on my machine.

I find two solutions:
1. Type `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl` in Terminal, then reboot.
2. rename the Xcode 8.2.1 to `Xcode8`,restart Xcode8, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this same issue for the first time (I've been using various versions of Xcode for over a year, maybe two).

After reviewing these threads, I noticed that my MacBook Pro had a pending update and could not install the update because Xcode was open.  I closed/quit Xcode, installed the update, forced quit all open apps, restarted my laptop and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This still (May 2017) happens to me occasionally in Xcode 8.3.2. Quitting Xcode is not enough to clear it up. Logging out and logging back in fixed it for me. I did not have to run a command line tool or reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Not to downplay the discussion above, but I tried all the solutions proposed above and all failed. Finally I updated Xcode to the latest Version 9.3 (2018) and everything works now!

Comment: I'm on Xcode 9.3.1 and seeing this issue intermittently still.

Comment: @Jeremiah I changed it to option+/ and it never fails again.