# Why Xcode's Add Documentation not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode10.2

Xcode-Editor-Structure-Add Documentation not working on my Mac. 
And I troubleshoot shortcut conflict.

I tried [Key Bindings Set] changed [Structure-Add Documentation] Key or restore, didn't working.

iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, 2017)macOS Mojave 10.14.5
Xcode 10.2.1

Anyone help me, Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Go to your applications folder and rename Xcode to whatever you want, then open the Xcode. Check to see if the comment selection now works, if so, you can go back and rename Xcode to its default name. If not, rename Xcode back to its original name anyway, and continue searching for another solution.

⸺ from [joe_04_04 in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40604230/11752142).